# Как запретить доступ на просмотр файла php?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Надо запретить доступ на просмотр нескольких файлов (их может быть тысячи). Например: `header.php, footer.php`, (они находятся в `/include/тут`.

**Как это сделать?**

Так, чтобы пользователь видел ошибку **404** например, но другой скрипт видел этот файл (например `index.php`, `include_once 'include/header.php'`;).

Я думал брать условием, если текущий адрес например: localhost/include/header.php, то выводить 404. Как это правильней сделать?

Comment: если условием, то $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Парсишь его и в условие. Можно регуляркой искать нужные вхождения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно было бы вынести этот каталог за пределы корня сайта. Это самое надежное решение.

Чуть менее правильно было бы сделать это на стороне сервера. Например, в nginx это делается так:

```
location /include/ {
    internal;
}
```

Если так, как выше, сделать нельзя, то можно в файле с настройками или прямо в `index.php` определить функцию, которая ничего не делает. Затем в начале каждого файла в каталоге `include` вызывать эту функцию. Так как функция будет неизвестна если файл вызывается напрямую, то будет ошибка и выполнение остановится.

Пример функции из файла с настройками:

```
function internal() {}
```

Пример использования:

```
<?php
internal();
// дальше обычный код
// который не выполнится если функция выше не определена
// а определена она будет только если этот файл включается откуда-то
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, нужно запретить прямой переход по ссылке, так?

Я это делал так:

Поскольку сайт был по модели mvc и всё грузилось из index.php, то в этом index.php я дефайнил переменную, например так - define("VALID_CALL", true), и если на странице эта переменная не isset (а установлена она может быть только в index.php), значит вызов был не из индекса - запрещаем дальнейшую загрузку страницы или выводим своё сообщение с ошибкой.